# Failing: Performing addition to a data frame and storing it in a data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to add some constant values to a data frame.

I have successfully done multiplication, but now addition does not work.

**This works:**

```
df_C2H_TT_y1['DURATION_H'] = df_C2H_TT_y1['DURATION_H'] * 0.95
```

**This does not work:**

```
TT_Base = pd.DataFrame
TT_Base["TT"] = (0.05 + A2C_TT_x2['DURATION_H']) + 0.25 + df_C2H_TT_y1['DURATION_H'] + 0.58333333333333333333333333333333)
TT_Base
```

This is an error: **'type' object does not support item assignment**

**What is wrong here?**

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a dataframe by adding parenthesis:

```
TT_Base = pd.DataFrame()
```

Comment: It still gives me `5        NaN
10       NaN
23       NaN
31       NaN
44       NaN`

Comment: Does df_C2H_TT_y1['DURATION_H'] or A2C_TT_x2['DURATION_H'] have missing values?

Comment: Nope. There are no missing values.

Comment: Could you print the df_C2H_TT_y1['DURATION_H'] or A2C_TT_x2['DURATION_H'] and show the results?

Comment: @LearningLogic You need to add `.values` Try `A2C_TT_x2['DURATION_H'].values` and `df_C2H_TT_y1['DURATION_H']`. It should work now

Comment: @ExploringAI Perfect! It is working now